# Mimic curl working script in Guzzle (multipart data with binary uploads together)

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data, guzzle, stability

I have curl command that works perfectly (using img2img via Stability API):

```bash
curl --request POST 'https://api.stability.ai/v1/generation/stable-diffusion-xl-1024-v1-0/image-to-image' \
    --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer somesecrettoken' \
    --form 'init_image=@"/full/path/to/init_image.png"' \
    --form 'text_prompts[0][text]=Beautiful php code' \
    --output '/full/path/to/response.json'
```

I've tried this PHP code with Guzzle v.6.5.8 which gives me HTTP 520:

```php
(new Client())
->post(
    'https://api.stability.ai/v1/generation/stable-diffusion-xl-1024-v1-0/image-to-image',
    [
        RequestOptions::HEADERS   => [
            'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer somesecrettoken',
            'Content-Type'  => 'multipart/form-data',
        ],
        RequestOptions::MULTIPART => [
            [
                'name'     => 'text_prompts[0][text]',
                'contents' => 'Beautiful php code',
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'init_image',
                'contents' => (new File('/full/path/to/init_image.png'))->getContent(),
//                'contents' => \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::tryFopen('/full/path/to/init_image.png', 'rb'), // This won't work too
            ],
        ],
        RequestOptions::SINK      => '/full/path/to/response.json',
        RequestOptions::DEBUG     => true,
    ],
)
```

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Assuming that `app.stability.key` contains only your `somesecrettoken`, your `Authorization` header would be missing the `Bearer` keyword.

Comment: Also, leaving out the `Content-Type` header might be a good idea. This header eventually needs to include the _boundary_ value the library used to separate the individual parts of this request - and when using `RequestOptions::MULTIPART`, it should add this header, including the boundary value, on its own. If you explicitly specify it, it might(!) be that this overwrites what the library would create by itself, and then the boundary would be missing.

Comment: @CBroe, yes, i had this bug with Bearer. Thank you! I fixed that but still getting same 520 error.

Comment: Whoa! You were right about Content-Type. I was required to use this header in `text-to-image` because they have options. You can write a proper answer so i'll accept it =^.^=

Comment: Yup, because of CF error, i had zero additional information – empty response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `app.stability.key` contains only your `somesecrettoken`, your `Authorization` header would be missing the `Bearer` keyword.

Also, leaving out the `Content-Type` header might be a good idea. This header eventually needs to include the boundary value the library used to separate the individual parts of this request - and when using `RequestOptions::MULTIPART`, it should add this header, including the boundary value, on its own. If you explicitly specify it, it might be that this overwrites what the library would create by itself, and then the boundary would be missing.